# Authentication in a html/knockoutjs application that communicates with WebAPI services

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, security

We are building an application that will use HTML and knockoutjs as the client. This will use ajax calls to communicate with WepApi services on the server side.

I have started looking into the security side of this and there doesn't seem to be any out of the box solution for authenticating a user for this type of RESTful communications with a server. We need more than basic authentication and I have looked at HMAC and this seems a good solution but I don't understand how the user gets the private key in this case?

Can anybody give pointers, suggestions of good patterns or practices that are usually implemented for this type of system

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HMAC-based authentication, there is a [hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk) scheme by Eran Hammer. Here is a .NET implementation by [Pablo](https://github.com/pcibraro/hawknet). I have created one very recently too, available in [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/lbadri/hawk-for-asp.net-web-api/overview) but mine is for ASP.NET Web API only.

The problem with using HMAC based stuff with JavaScript is that your JavaScript must have the access to the shared secret key, which may or may not be desirable, depending on your needs. HMAC based solutions typically use a shared symmetric key, meaning both the sender and receiver share the same key, which they use to create the HMAC for the other end to verify. This is not exactly the asymmetric key pairs of public-private keys.

An alternative to HMAC-based solution will be to use an authentication broker which will issue a token such as JWT which can be used to authenticate to web API. The advantage whith a token is that it is typically short-lived as against a key or the user id/password. Here you can use implicit grant flow of OAuth 2.0 or without using any standard protocol, just do a POST or something like that to obtain a token from the issuer. Before rolling your own stuff, you can try to reuse existing implementations like [thinktecture identity server](http://thinktecture.github.io/), for example.